# FirebaseAuth creating custom tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

When you create a custom token using the below method, is a unique token generated every time even if the uid is the same? Or will it always generate the same token for the same uid in an application?

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid)
```

Also, how long is the generated token valid for? For the lifetime of the application until revoked?

Answer (score 0):

> When you create a custom token using the below method, is a unique token generated every time even if the uid is the same?

Unique every time.

> Also, how long is the generated token valid for?

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) says they expire after 1 hour.

If you use that token to [sign in using a Firebase client libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients), it will [refresh automatically every hour as needed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions).

Comment: I've tested this and seen that the same token is generated - but that was within one hour. I didn't know if this was for sure though.

Comment: Also from my testing the token generated with createCustomToken seems to be able to be used to sign in to the client libs indefinitely. Once signed in, token ids are generated which last one hour. My question is this: can I use the token generated with createCustomToken to sign into firebase indefinitely? Let's say I generate it today, can I use it to sign in a year later? Or does it expire at some point? If so, can I set it to never expire? Thank you.

Comment: No. The documentation says the token expires after 1 hour. It would be a security hole if they lasted indefinitely.  The refresh token behavior is a different thing that requires the client to keep getting new refresh tokens to stay signed in.  You can revoke those tokens as described in the documentation (as a security measure), which will require the client app to request another custom token in order to sign in again.

Comment: Let me explain my use case: I want to use createCustomToken to create a token one time for a constant uid for a user and save it in my database. When that user logs in via a 3rd party service, they get that token from the database and use it to log in to firebase client side. My question is, do I need to regenerate that token via createCustomToken every time they log in? Or will creating it one time and storing it in my database be enough since it can be used indefinitely? (unless of course I revoke it with revokeRefreshTokens(uid)) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You need to generate a new token for every sign-in.  You can't store them effectively, since they expire after an hour.

Comment: I noticed that if a user uses the token to sign in to a firebase client (such as a mobile app) but then does not open or use the app for a long time (6 months) and then opens the app again, the user is still authenticated. If what you say is correct, the user shouldn't be able to use the app since it has been well over one hour. Perhaps I am misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: As I explained earlier, the Firebase client library will automatically use refresh tokens on a regular basis after signing in with the custom token in order to keep the user signed in.  I suggest reading over the documentation I linked to one more time.

Comment: You said "the Firebase client library will automatically use refresh tokens on a regular basis after signing in with the custom token in order to keep the user signed in" - but what if the client is a mobile app and the user has not opened it in months? The client library would not have had any chance to refresh that token. I don't see this explained well in the docs.

Comment: It will use the old refresh token to get a new ID token.  As I mentioned before, those refresh tokens are a different thing than the custom token that you use for sign-in.  The link I gave for token refresh explains this.  If the user doesn't have the app open, there is simply no need for an active ID token that can be used to validate the user's identity with Firebase services.  The refresh token is persisted by the SDK and can always be used to get a new ID token until it's revoked.